# In C89, how can I truncate and split a double precision floating point into two 32-bit words?

Tags: c, c99, c89, ansi-c

When targeting C99, I could truncate and split a `double` value into two 32-bit integers with the following code:

```
#include <stdint.h>

void split(double d, unsigned long *most_significant_word, unsigned long *least_significant_word)
{
   uint64_t i = (uint64_t)d;
   *most_significant_word = i >> 32;
   *least_significant_word = i & 0xffffffff;
}
```

C89 however, does not seem to define a 64-bit integer type, so I can't use the compiler to perform the truncation. Even if the truncation was not necessary(the value already represented an integer) I also could not use bit operators like `&` or `>>` since these don't work on `double` values.

So, how can the above `split()` function be implemented in pure C89(and thus without relying on 64-bit integers), returning the 21/32 bit words that make up a 53-bit integer stored in a `double` value?

Comment: C89 does not provide `stdint.h`. You are left to implementation specific details. As it does not provide `long long`, how do you read the 64 bit value?

Comment: @Olaf: however, C89 mandates `long` to be at least 32 bit wide. Using `unsigned long` should be fine for the outputs.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: And how does that contradict my comment? I think I clearly wrote it is **implementation specific**, not impossible. Just relying on `long` to have 32 bits is very wrong. See POSIX64! A bigger problem is the 64 bit type, though.

Comment: @Olaf: I thought you were referring to the output type; the 64 bit type is irrelevant, you can do all the math in `double`.

Comment: @Olaf What's wrong with an `int[2]`, assuming `int` is 32  bits wide? The 32-bit wide type will need to be determined, of course, but in the most used cases that's just `int` anyway.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: HJow do you represent 64 bits mantissa in a 64 bit `double`?? And using floating point for integer calculations a a very bad idea in general, even **iff** it can represent all bits.

Comment: @Olaf: there's no 64 bit mantissa in a 64 bit double, what are you talking about? Did you read the original code? The input is a `double`, he's using a `uint64_t` just as a temporary store to perform bitwise operations on it, but the source of data is an integer stored inside a `double`.

Comment: @rubenvb: Your question includes its answer: "assuming int is 32 bits wide". Please read what _implementation defined_ means! I'm not in the mood to repeat it again.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: Exactly! Did **you** read the question? To cite your comment: "you can do all the math in `double`".

Comment: `(uint64_t)d` causes undefined behaviour if `d > UINT64_MAX`. Have you got a precondition that `d` is never that large?

Comment: @M.M I did not consider this, but I can add such precondition into the program, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignoring the sign (as does the original code) it should be as simple as this:

```
void split(double d, unsigned long *most_significant_word, unsigned long *least_significant_word)
{
   *most_significant_word = d/4294967296.; // d>>32 in double
   *least_significant_word = fmod(d, 4294967296.);
}
```

To take negative numbers into consideration, operate on the absolute value then compute the two's complement:

```
void split(double d, unsigned long *most_significant_word, unsigned long *least_significant_word)
{
   double dabs = d < 0 ? -d : d;
   *most_significant_word = dabs/4294967296.;
   *least_significant_word = fmod(dabs, 4294967296.);
   if (d < 0) {
       *most_significant_word = ~*most_significant_word;
       *least_significant_word = ~*least_significant_word + 1;
       if (!*least_significant_word) *most_significant_word += 1;
   }
}
```

Comment: This is really simple, thanks. Just give me a few minutes to test it. Would it be complicated to modify this answer so that the words contain the two's complement in case of negative numbers?

Comment: Better use `exp2()` instead of `pow()` for less-optimizing C compilers.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: unsigned integer overflow is well defined, and does what (I think) the OP is expecting, i.e. taking the lowest 32 bits of the integer stored in `d`, as the original code does. Of course if he wants to extract the raw bits of the double it's a whole different matter (best accomplished with a `memcpy`), but it isn't what the code he provided do.

Comment: @FUZxxl: I changed it straight to a `double` literal for good measure.

Comment: `(unsigned long)d` causes undefined behaviour if `d > ULONG_MAX` (or `d <= -1.0`)

Comment: @M.M: wops you are right, I thought that the usual "unsigned integer overflow is defined" applied, but when converting from FP it's not like that. No big deal, it can be fixed with an `fmod`.

Comment: @MatteoItalia it seems to work after a few tests, thanks. What would I need to change in order to make this compatible with `d < 0`, where the 32-bit words contain the two's complement representing the truncated negative integer?

Comment: I have edited the answer to consider negative numbers, can someone review it?

Comment: @Thiago de Arruda I hope Matteo Italia likes your edit.  I would not appreciate such a large edit by someone else on an active question.  Especially after it has been accepted.